# How can I enable access only to a specific plugin (Newsletter) to a new user on the wordpress admin dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, access-control, newsletter

I am using the [Newsletter](https://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/) plugin to send newsletters from my Wordpress website. I want to create a new user who can **only** access the Newsletter plugin and not have any other admin capability on the admin dashboard.

How do I do that?

I have been experimenting with different access-control plugins, but none seem to have the capability to toggle access for a user/role to **another** plugin.

Would greatly appreciate if someone can point me to a plugin or a piece of code that can make the magic happen.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be quite simple eventually.

The newsletter plugin, in the **advanced settings** option in its **settings** tab, provides a checkbox to allow certain user roles to access the plugin.

I just enabled it for a non-admin role that worked for me, and voila!